# Listar a quantidade de espaço ocupada por um tipo de arquivo no terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, osx, centos

Eu desconfio que os PCs que utilizo possuem muitos arquivos `.RData`, utilizados pelo programa R para salvar conjuntos de dados. Estou querendo fazer uma limpeza nestes arquivos, mas sem entrar em diretório por diretório, em computador por computador. Além disso, utilizo computadores com pelo menos 3 sistemas operacionais diferentes: macOS, Ubuntu e CentOS.

Já pesquisei na internet e o comando

```
find . -iname '*RData' -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=-
```

encontra os arquivos que desejo, além de calcular o espaço ocupado por cada um deles. Entretanto, só funciona no Ubuntu e no CentOS. Quando tento rodar no macOS, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
du: illegal option -- f
usage: du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] 
[-I mask] [file ...]
```

O que faz sentido, pois ao contrário do `du` do Ubuntu e do CentOS, o `du` do macOS não possui a flag `--files0-from`.

Como posso fazer para resolver este problema no macOS? Imagino que não seja através do `du`, mas será que existe alguma maneira de fazer isto via terminal? Estou utilizando o bash 4.4.12(1)-release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solução com os utilitários `find` + `du` + `awk`:

```
$ find . -iname "*RData" | du | awk '{bytes+=$1} END{print bytes}'
```

Comment: Parece-me que `du` sem argumentos, ignora completamente a STDIN -- ou seja vai dar um resultado diferente do esperado (dá o tamanho da directoria corrente).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*RData" -exec du -c {} +
```